# why the ng-token-auth making issue with ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ngroute

I'm trying to use the **ng-token-auth** to make authentication for my app

but when I included the **ng-token-auth** to my model I found it stopped my routes and it gives me this issue

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=HiringApp&p1=Error%…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fhiring-angular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)
```

this is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module("HiringApp",['ngRoute','ngCookies','ng-token-auth']);

// define my routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/login',
    {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
  $routeProvider.when('/register',
    {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
    });
  $routeProvider.when('/jobs',
    {
        templateUrl: 'views/jobs.html',
        controller: 'JobsController'
    });
  $routeProvider.otherwise ({redirectTo: '../index.html'});
});
```

and I included the required js libraries in my html file such as

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-token-auth/0.0.27/ng-token-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

why I got this issue ?
when I only remove it "ng-token-auth" the app work so why ?

Comment: show me the code please

Comment: This is my code , I typed it in the question !!!

Comment: change your library loading sequence load ng-auth-auth.js in last

Comment: I already tried it before but I gotted the same issue

Comment: do you assign ng-app="myApp"

Comment: sure , I said when I remove the "ng-token-auth" the app work well

Comment: just a min let me check the ng-auth-token

Comment: Follow the steps

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/blob/master/README.md

Comment: man I readed it a lot and followed the documentation step :(

Comment: ok create a plunkr or fiddle sample

Comment: here you can find simple code http://plnkr.co/edit/hKhJGCVw0WZbd5RXD3LD?p=preview
just now try to add the ng-token-auth for my model  and you will see that the links will stop getting the view